# New database records not showing until I restart the application

Tags: vb6, ado, recordset

I have a problem when I move to the next form, the record that I've just added does not show. For example I typed "123456" then go the next form, and it will just show the previous record, not the "123456".
It will only show when I stop the program then run it again and the "123456" will show on the second form's textbox.

Form1 code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Form2.Hide
    Form1.Show
    Adodc1.Recordset.Update
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Adodc1.Recordset.AddNew
End Sub
```

Form2 code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Adodc1.Recordset.Update
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Adodc1.Refresh
    Adodc1.Recordset.MoveLast
End Sub
```

Does anyone know why it's not showing until I restart?

Comment: Seriously, questions can only rarely be both VBA and VB6.  Sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the Jet database engine using lazy writes as answered in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486970/why-is-my-access-database-not-up-to-date-when-i-read-it-from-another-process).

Answer (score 0):

Using you ADO Data Controls with a DataEnvironment should eliminate the use of separate Connections to the database.  I suspect that's really where your headaches are coming from.

If you are using VBA all bets are off, but then **you should not have tagged your question VB6!**

Answer (score 0):

Some note for ADODC:

- For refresh state: `Adodc1.Recordset.Requery`
- If you use DataGrid or any controller for update records, you must leave the currently edited record before committing changes. (the currently edited row is not a change in DataGrid)