# Duration of insert query in msaccess

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I would like to know how to get the time needed by the

> INSERT

query in a msaccess database.

I use an OleDbCommand and of course an OleDbConnection object

I am running a loop like :

```
 For Each item In ListBox.SelectedItems

                Try

                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table(x) VALUES(" + item.ToString + ")"
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            Next
```

and just afterwards I fill another listbox by getting these items recently inserted in the database.

code for 2nd listbox:

> SELECT items FROM table

```
for each item returned by query: 
listbox2.addItem(item) 
end loop
```

I have a slow connection so my 2nd listbox doesn't get filled right away.

By putting my thread to sleep for 5s and then running the `SELECT` query solves my problem because only after 5s I can see the newly inserted data, but it's not always like this, I may need to wait for 4s or even 7s.I hope the `Try` does not slow down the process.

Comment: How are you creating connections to the database, particularly on the writes?

Comment: @Rob Hi,
I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why re-query the database. Just populate the second list box with the same value you INSERTed. Just be sure to do that after the Try Catch completes. Or return a scalar to check to be certain the insert worked then add your item to the second list box. That way you need not re-query, which is by far the slowest bottle neck.

Also, if you must re query, are you closing and reopening your connection? If so don't, just leave it open until you are all done with the db.

Answer (score 1):

It is a caching issue.

The answers and linked articles in this question explain it:

[Why is my Access database not up-to-date when I read it from another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486970/why-is-my-access-database-not-up-to-date-when-i-read-it-from-another-process)